# How to restrict the key-board operation to change the check-box value?

Tags: wpf, checkbox, wpfdatagrid

I have loaded the check-box in the DataGrid cell of a custom column, i like to restrict the Editing operation for that column So that i have customize the Column externally and then make the Check-box property IsHitTestVisible as false to restrict the editing operation for the check-box using mouse.But i am able to change the check-box status using the key-board(Space key). How to avoid this and makes the check-box completely in the non-editable state.

Code snippet`

```
< CustomDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
                   Editing="True" IsReadOnly="True"
                   Grouping="True" 
                   AutoPopulateColumns="False"
                   DataSource="{Binding Path=OrdersDetails}">
   < CustomDataGrid.Columns>
//I like to restrict the editing for the Closed column, Like IsReadOnly property of the Text-Box,
I am able to achieve this using the IsHitVisible as false,This helps only for mouse click But I am not able to restrict the key opeartion 
           <MyDataGridCheckBoxColumn Text="Closed"  Items="{Binding IsClosed}" />
   < CustomDataGrid.Columns>
 <CustomDataGrid/>
`
```

Comment: what have you currently tried? Code examples?

Comment: Hi @GingerNinja Please find the code which i have used in My Grid

Comment: Have you tried using a `ControlTemplates`?

Answer (score 0):

While it is unclear as to all your custom columns and the requirements. This should be able to be solved with a Template for the given Column. I Mocked up a quick example:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Tester}" Width="280">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Value}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Checked" Width="80">
                <!-- Should be able to put a similar Template on MyDataGridCheckBoxColumn-->
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                        </CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

With this I am unable to change the checkbox with the Mouse and the Keyboard.